# PHP post to url

Tags: php, python, redirect, joomla

I have a python script that listen to specific port on a server and waits until it gets an http request from browser or program to run.

I want that script to run when the admin on my Joomla site clicks on the save button.

That means that I need a way to go to the link that the server listens to without showing it to the the user (a way to do it in the background).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you look up using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` is server side, so anything implemented there would not be visible to your user, unless it gets rendered as HTML output.

Does the request need to come from the client machine? Or can it come from your web server?

If it needs to come from the client, I would recommend using PHP headers.

Script 1

```
header("Location: exec_something_private.php");
```

exec_something_private.php

```
exec("do something");
header("Location: success.php");
```

The above implementation could call a php file, do what you need to do, and then redirect them immediately to a new page?

If the function can be called by the webserver, simply uses `exec` to run a `curl` request or something, no?

Comment: Actually I tried already the curl, and it didn't worked, the problems was that curl want installed on my Apache server. But your answer helped me in many ways to realize that and solve the problem. Thanks!!